# Return JSON with data from MongoDB

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongodb-ruby

I am fetching data from MongoDB as follows:

```
@bs = coll2.find("date" => {"$gte" => initial_date, "$lte" => Time.now.utc})
```

It works fine but when I render @bs, it sends empty.

```
  render :json => @bs
```

If I do a @bs.each and render each one as json, it works, however, I want to send the whole @bs.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `#find` returns a Mongo::Cursor object, not the actual results. You'll want to first convert the cursur (`@bs`) to an array with the results in it, and then render that as json.

```
render :json => @bs.to_a.to_json
```

Note that since it's a cursor, once you either return the results, or start iterating over them, then the `to_a` call will not return all the results. You'll need to call `rewind!` to reset the result set:

```
> @bs.to_a
# => [{"_id" => BSON::ObjectID.....]
> @bs.to_a
# => []
> @bs.rewind!
# => true
> @bs.to_a
# => [{"_id" => BSON::ObjectID.....]
```

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense. How do I conver the cursor to an array? Is there a simple way of doing it?

Comment: The `@bs.to_a` part of my example does that for you. Then you call `to_json` on the array to get JSON data.

Comment: I'm still getting [] but @bs is returning results.

Comment: Make sure you're not doing anything with `@bs` before the `to_a` call (i.e. the `to_a` call should be the first thing you do to `@bs` after running your `find` query). Since it's a cursor, doing something like `@bs.each...` will leave it pointing at the end of the result set. So when you then do `@bs.to_a` it returns an empty array.

Comment: Alternatively, you can call `@bs.rewind!` before the `to_a` to reset the result set.